gitlab-ci.yml changes rules?how to use it
I want a job to trigger when *.py files without 'setting' in their names are modified. How should I modify the code?:
  rules:
    - if: |
        $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" &&
        $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" &&
        $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME !~ /^format/
      changes:
        - ${PROJECT_DIR}/**/*.py

update this code block
